# java overriding not working

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in Java, I used PHP, C++ and Lua and never had this problem, I made two classes just for exercising's sake `Facto` and `MyFacto`, first one does find a factorial and the second one should find factorial not by adding, but by multiplying. Don't blame me for the stupid and pointless code, I am just testing and trying to get the hang of Java.

Main:

```
public class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Facto fc = new Facto(5);
    fc.calc();
    System.out.println(fc.get());   

    MyFacto mfc = new MyFacto(5);
    mfc.calc();
    System.out.println(mfc.get());

}
}
```

Facto.java:

```
public class Facto {
private int i;
private int res;

public Facto(int i) {
    this.i = i;
}

public void set(int i) {
    this.i = i;
}

public int get() {
    return this.res;
}

public void calc() {
    this.res = this.run(this.i);
}

private int run(int x) {
    int temp = 0;
    if(x>0) {
        temp = x + this.run(x-1);
    }
    return temp;
}
}
```

MyFacto.java:

```
public class MyFacto extends Facto {
public MyFacto(int i) {
    super(i);
}

private int run(int x) {
    int temp = 0;
    if(x>0) {
        temp = x * this.run(x-1);
    }
    return temp;
}
}
```

I thought the result should be 15 and 120, but I get 15 and 15. Why is that happening? Does it have something to do with `calc()` method not being overriden and it uses the `run()` method from the `Facto` class? How can I fix this or what is the right way to override something like this?

Comment: Change `private int run()` to `protected int run()` in both classes.

Comment: @GregKopff Where exactly, in `Facto` class or `MyFacto`? I changed in both of them and the result is 15 and 0.

Comment: because 0 * anything = 0. i.e. Your override is now working correctly, work on logic. =)

Comment: God damn late night programming :) Thank you very much, could someone explain why does it work with `protected`? @GregKopff could you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you're running into issues is due to [member access visibility](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

In a nutshell:

- `public` allows *any* Java class to see the field/function, so long as it can be reached.
- `<package>`, or no apparent modifier, allows any Java object (but not subclasses) to see the field/function, as long as they're in the same directory, or package.
- `protected` allows the declared class and *all other subclasses* to access that field/function, as well as any class in the same directory/package.
- `private` allows **only** the declared class to access that field/function.

Comment: Thank you! Somehow I overlooked I made it private, when looking in to the code I saw it was public, oh that late-night programming! Thank you for your explanation!

Answer (score 3):

To expand on what @Makoto said, you're running into an issue because the `calc()` method of `Facto` does not have access to the `run()` method of `MyFacto`, so it's using it's own `run()` method. Changing them both to `protected` instead of `private` should do the trick.

Also, something you should probably learn to use is the `@Override` annotation. It's good practice to put it above any method that you are overriding. That way, if you misspell something, or the parameters don't match, you will get a warning. Also, it makes it clear to you and/or the reader. For example:

MyFacto.java#run:

```
@Override
protected int run(int x) {
    int temp = 0;
    if(x>0) {
        temp = x * this.run(x-1);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Good luck with Java!

Comment: Didn't realise you had worked it out when I posted, glad it's all fine now. :)

Comment: Nevertheless your comment was helpful, I tried to annotate with `@Override`, but had an error `The method run(int) of type MyFacto must override or implement a supertype method`, couldn't find out what it really means so I erased it, I will use it from now on then. Is there any other reason to use `@Override` annotation other than readability and getting errors in the IDE?

Comment: @Vlakarados: The point of `@Override` is to catch exactly the problem you faced - you thought you were overriding a method when you weren't.